# Get differences between today and yesterday's records

Tags: crystal-reports

I have three columns named:

- Planned Cost
- Create Date
- Change in Planned Cost

In the column *[Change in Planned Cost]*, I need it to display the differences between yesterday's and today's planned cost (*[Planned Cost]* where *[Create Date]* = currentdate substract *[Planned Cost]* where *[Create Date]* = currentdate - 1.)

I have the *[Change in Planned Cost]* as a formula field but I can't come up with a formula for it.

Comment: where do you want to show this in report?

Comment: I am using Crystal Report 2008 and the report will be shown in Business Object.